# I add some js files from a plugin to a specific location

Tags: widgets, actions, wp-head, jquery-ui

How Can I add some js files from a plugin to a specific location with add_action

I am Using this widget: 
http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-plugins/wordpress-plugin-jquery-vertical-accordion-menu-widget/

It is adding its file here:
  After

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://new.dajewelers.com/wp-includes/js/l10n.js?         ver=20101110'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://new.dajewelers.com/wp- includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.4'></script>
```

and before these lines:

```
   <script type='text/javascript' src='http://new.dajewelers.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui.core.js?ver=1.8.9'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://new.dajewelers.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui.widget.js?ver=1.8.9'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://new.dajewelers.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui.tabs.js?ver=1.8.9'></script>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='http://new.dajewelers.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui.mouse.js?ver=1.8.9'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://new.dajewelers.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui.resizable.js?ver=1.8.9'></script>
```

Its code is basically for accordion and I think it is not working because it is coming before JQuery.ui files. So I want it to come after UI Files.

Please can some one figure out the problem or if same is problem then how to fix that.

And this is wp code that is doing so

```
    if(!is_admin()){
        // Header styles
        add_action( 'wp_head', array('dc_jqaccordion', 'header') );

        // Scripts
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jqueryhoverintent', dc_jqaccordion::get_plugin_directory() . '/js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquerycookie', dc_jqaccordion::get_plugin_directory() . '/js/jquery.cookie.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'dcjqaccordion', dc_jqaccordion::get_plugin_directory() . '/js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.8.js', array('jquery') );
    }
```

Here is the link where all this is : http://new.dajewelers.com

Please tell if you have any idea.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a $ undefined js error on line 191. wp_enqueue_script has a dependencies parameter, I think you need to pass the jquery-ui handle as a dependency with your accordion script so it loads first.